# Handling exceptions of same type thrown by two separate statements

Tags: java, exception

Below code snippet throws error
1. When input file path is invalid - FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION
2. When output file is open in excel - FILENOTFOUNDEXCEPTION saying said file is open in another process

I want to suggest user to either check input file path or close open excel(or open in notepad instead). How do I catch these separately?

```
try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Test.log");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);) {      

        doSomething(br);

        //writing to CSV
        String[]  arr = {"aaa","bbb"};
        FileWriter outputfile= new 
        FileWriter("D:/output.csv",false); 
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile); 
            writer.writeNext(arr);
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate code to two try/cath statments

```
BufferedReader br;
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/Test.log");
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("Input file not found");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

doSomething(br);

//writing to CSV
String[]  arr = {"aaa","bbb"};

try {
    FileWriteroutputfile = new FileWriter("D:/output.csv",false);
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile);
    writer.writeNext(arr);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    log.error("Output file already in use");
}
```